# Cocos2d CCAnimation delay less than .05f problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to animate a CCSprite with CCAnimation. I have 100 Frames, but if I run it with a delay of .05f it's too slow. I try to put it .03f and .01f and it didin't complete the animation.

Any idea?

`walkAnimFrames` has the 100 frames

```
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.05f];
            CCRepeat *repeat = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim] times:1];
            [scoreSrpite runAction:repeat];
```

Or should I use only 50 frames. This is like a scorebar that its filling depending on the actual score

Thanks

Comment: you're not the only one, it seems to be a bug

Comment: mm :S I hope that any user need to execute the 100 frame at once. If not I will put it to delay the second and so on updates.

Answer (score 1):

try this method :

```
[scoreSrpite setDisplayFrame:[walkAnimFrames objectAtIndex:0]];
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.05f];
CCRepeat *repeat = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim] times:1];
[scoreSrpite runAction:repeat];
```